# Broadcast receiver to output access point data when wifi is enabled

Tags: android, wifi, broadcast, wifimanager

```
public class broadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        int linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
        String BSSID = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
        String SSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        String MAC = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
        System.out.println("IP - "+ ipAddress +" |MAC - "+ MAC +" |Speed - "+ linkSpeed +" |BSSID - "+ BSSID +" |SSID - "+ SSID);
    }
}
```

I am able to access the methods of wifiManager, but not that of wifiInfo as it is always null. I dont understand why wifiInfo is null. I want to get all the wifiInfo details(ipaddress, link speed, SSID, etc) and write it to a file.

Why wifiInfo is null and how this can be fixed?

Comment: what intent are you registered to receive ?

Comment: WIFI_STATE_CHANGED .. i have even tried with SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION ..

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you found a fix for it yet?